# Unexpected result from array.splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a JavaScript function to knock out items in an array and return the final item. However this is actually removing items from the main array when it shouldn't be.

Function:

```
function oneRemaining(arr) {
    tmp = arr;
    while (tmp.length > 1) {
        tmp.splice(~~(Math.random() * tmp.length), 1);
    }
    return tmp[0];
}
```

So after running this, the array that went in should still be the same because it was never altered however when I run this in console, only 1 item is in it.

Why does the input array get altered?

Comment: @faintsignal It doesn't get the last element of the array. It gets the last remaining element after the others are removed. In my mind it's more random than just selecting a random element in the array (`arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)]`)

Comment: Oh man I am suffering from tunnel vision. I made my comment based on reading 'return the final item'. Of course then my comment didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your array changes because:

1. You created a reference not a clone/copy (you are touching the same array in the end)
2. Splice changes the underlying array, it's one of the few methods that does so (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

If you want that to work replace your second line for:

```
tmp = arr.concat([])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

it is getting altered because `tmp` is a reference to `arr` not a copy of it. WHenever you change something in a referenced object it changes the original as well

Answer (score 0):

Array are reference type in javascript so the following line do not copy the input array it just assign the variable tmp with the reference of the input array. At the end you always edit the same array in memory.

```
tmp = arr;
```

You can use arr.slice(0) to really copy your input array.

(And you might have missed a var in from of the declaration of the variable tmp, except if you want it to be global?)